# What GIS applications use Google Glass?

Tags: mobile, remote-sensing, google

[image]
From [techcrunch](http://techcrunch.com/2013/01/21/sergey-brin-dons-google-glass-dresses-like-an-international-jewel-thief-for-nyc-subway-ride/).

I see a lot of press coverage about [Google Glass](http://www.google.com/glass/start/), yet I haven't seen details of GIS apps that use it.

What GIS applications use Google Glass?

Comment: Are they that widely available? Anecdote (TL:DR): TMZ caught a young woman wearing one this week. She wasn't a recognized celebrity so someone in the bullpen asked who it was. She turned out to be Sergey Brin's wife, Anne Wojcicki.

Comment: @mkennedy  Ahh, now I see.  I should've looked closer, like [here](http://news.cnet.com/8301-17852_3-57571637-71/dubious-google-glass-ebay-auction-hammered/).  Still, maybe someone from the gis community has proposed something in their #ifihadglass application that they'd be willing to share?

Comment: I've got an early prototype pair of these - all be it without full operability. That said, they allow me to "stream" a 1:1 scale, photo-realistic, fully 3D representation of the world ;)

Comment: @AndyTIce Cool, can you collect data with them too?  Any problems with a [thousand yard stare](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thousand-yard_stare)?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_reality#Navigation Nokia have it already http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=Zg-_9jj86NY - Shame Glass is only for the US residents only.

Comment: @Mapperz Wow, Nokia looks cool. I see that Google [stopped collecting streetview imagery in Germany](http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2383363,00.asp).  Given that Glass can also operate as a collection device, I wonder if they see that as a problem.  While Google provides a way for people to opt out of be photo'd by Street view, I don't see how you could allow people to opt out of being photo'd by a crowd of people wearing Glass.

Comment: This company develop applications for Google glass  http://www.go-arc.com/

Comment: Looks like Strava (cycling fitness app) will be on Google glass http://www.cyclingweekly.co.uk/news/latest-news/strava-one-of-the-first-apps-on-google-glass-22305

Answer (score 1):

[GIS and Augmented Reality](http://www.agi.org.uk/storage/AGI2012-AR.pdf)
by Sung-Hyun Jang and Andrew Hudson-Smith